Quote Equation number with horizontal alignment
I have using quote with displayed numbered equation. But the eq number (1) not moved from right to left. Can anyone advise me how to fix.

Source TeX code is:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\def\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.125pt}

\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\newenvironment{smallquote}
  {\vspace*{4.2pt}\begin{quote}
   \fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont
   \setlength{\rightskip}{1pc}
   }
  {\vspace*{3pt}\end{quote}}
  

\begin{document}

<normal para text here>

\begin{smallquote}
The two bases are incompatible, so there is a trade-off between our uncertainty about $X$ and about $Z$, captured by the inequality
\be
S(X)+S(Z)\geq \log(1/c) \,,\quad c = \max_{x,z} |\langle x|z\rangle|^2\,.\label{uncert1}
\ee
We see that the lower bound on the total uncertainty is given by the maximum overlap between any two eigenvectors, that is, by the degree of mutual nonorthogonality of the two bases.
\end{smallquote}

<normal para text here>

\end{document}


\setlength{\rightskip}{1pc} breaks the latex layout as you have set the tex primitive without the rest of the latex structure being aware of this so the paragraph text is indented on the right by 1pc but latex does not change the width of the displayed equation. Note that you should not use \be \ee it happens to work with equation but any math environments defined by amsmath will not work with the environment syntax hidden.

@DavidCarlisle - i got it now. Thanks for the answer.

quote is based on \list and doesn't like \rightskip to be set.
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\def\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.125pt}

\newenvironment{smallquote}{%
  \list{}{\rightmargin=\dimeval{\leftmargin+1pc}}%
  \fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont\item\relax
}{\endlist}
  

\begin{document}

We see that the lower bound on the total uncertainty is given by 
the maximum overlap between any two eigenvectors, that is, by the 
degree of mutual nonorthogonality of the two bases.

\begin{smallquote}
The two bases are incompatible, so there is a trade-off between 
our uncertainty about $X$ and about $Z$, captured by the inequality
\begin{equation}
S(X)+S(Z)\geq \log(1/c) \,,\quad
c = \max_{x,z} |\langle x|z\rangle|^2\,.\label{uncert1}
\end{equation}
We see that the lower bound on the total uncertainty is given by 
the maximum overlap between any two eigenvectors, that is, by the 
degree of mutual nonorthogonality of the two bases.
\end{smallquote}

We see that the lower bound on the total uncertainty is given by 
the maximum overlap between any two eigenvectors, that is, by the 
degree of mutual nonorthogonality of the two bases.

\end{document}

I guess you have 11pt (or 12pt) as main font size.

Like David (see comments to the question), I recommend not to use \be and \ee. You gain nothing in clarity and a good text editor will add the full names in less time you type \be and \ee.
In the definition of quote, the \rightmargin is set to be equal to the \leftmargin, so I just added 1pc to the standard setting.

Thanks for the detailed information.
